# Solving different kinds of prob questions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I have started to learn Probability. I have difficulties with solving some problems. I need help how to solve these kind of questions. I have wrote $3$ of them below:

1. Moment generating function of rv $X$ is $$m_X(t)=\frac16^{−} + \frac12^{−2} + \frac13^{−3}$$
   Find mean and variance of $X$.

---

2. Let $X$ be a geometric rv with parameter $p$. Show that $$P(  =  +  \mid   >  ) = P( = )$$

---

3. The probability $p$ of being able to log on to a computer from a remote terminal at any given time is $0.7$.

- a) What is the probability that at least $5$ attempts will be made to gain access to the computer?
- b) What is the expected number of attempts that must be made to gain access to the computer? (Define random variable for the question, determine its type and solve.)

Comment: It is recommended to ask one question at a time.

Comment: Have you missed a $6$ in the first exponent in the mgf?

Comment: @JimmyR. Not, It is written like that.

Comment: @drhab Ok, I will ask one question next time. But I need to get answer because other questions like to this one. So, I want to solve all questions.

Comment: In your second question is it $P(X=n)$ or $P(X=k)$ on the RHS?

Comment: @JimmyR. I wrote everything same as in the book. So it is right what I wrote there.  P(X=k).

Comment: When is this due?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The $n$-th moment $EX^n$of a rv $X$ with moment generating function $m_X(t)$ can be calculated as $$EX^n=\frac{d^nm_X(t)}{dt^n}\Bigg|_{t=0}$$ In your case, e.g. $$EX=\frac{dm_X(t)}{dt}\Bigg |_{t=0}=\left(-\frac16e^{-t}-\frac22e^{-2t}-\frac33e^{-3t}\right)\Bigg|_{t=0}=-\frac{13}6$$ To calculate the variance, recall that $$Var(X)=EX^2-\left(EX\right)^2$$so you just need to calculate the second moment $EX^2$ as above, by differentiating one more time.
2. Since $X\sim$geometric$(p)$, you know that $P(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$ for $k\ge1$. Hence \begin{align}P(X=n+k \mid X> n)&=\frac{P(X>n\mid X=n+k)P(X=n+k)}{P(X>n)}\\[0.4cm]&=\frac{1\cdot p(1-p)^{n+k-1}}{\sum_{m=n+1}^{+\infty}p(1-p)^{m-1}}=\frac{p(1-p)^{n}(1-p)^{k-1}}{p(1-p)^n\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}(1-p)^m}\\[0.4cm]&=\frac{(1-p)^{k-1}}{\frac1{1-(1-p)}}=p(1-p)^{k-1}=P(X=k)\end{align} By the way, this is called the memoryless property of the geometric distribution.
3. **Hint:** The number $X$ of times until the first success (first time to gain access) is a geometric random variable with parameter $p=0.7$. You want to find

   - a) $P(X\ge 5)$. Use 2. or that $P(X\ge 5)=1-P(X\le 4)$.
   - b) $E[X]$.

Comment: Thx, So for question 2 , can we say that it is done by memoryless thm ?

Comment: No, no shortcut thms...

Comment: name of this proof will be memoryless property ?

Comment: So, you ask 3 questions, I answer them, no upvote and you keep asking in the comments?

Comment: :)  I just want to learn. I did it :)

Comment: Ok, now I got my reward, so I am happy again :). Yes, it called the memoryless property, and the geometric distribution is the unique discrete distribution with this property. The unique continuous distribution with this property is the exponential